# Why doesn't the != operator work in my query in AGE?

Tags: postgresql, cypher, apache-age, opencypher

I am facing a problem when I try to use `STACK_MATCH` relationships to connect `Person` nodes having the 'backend' `title`, while avoiding `Person` nodes ending up being related to themselves.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('devbook', $$ 
    MATCH (a: Person), (b: Person) 
    WHERE a.title = 'backend' AND b.title = 'backend' AND id(a) != id(b)
    CREATE (a)-[e:STACK_MATCH { title: 'backend' }]->(b) RETURN e 
$$) as (relationship agtype);
```

The main problem is that the `!=` operator doesn't work. I've also tried using the `<>` operator, but it still creates relationships with other nodes that don't have the 'backend' title.

How can I use the != operator in the right way?

Comment: I would think twice before `CREATE`ing all those relationships. With `N` such `Person` nodes, you'd end up with `N*(N-1)` extra relationships, and every pair of such nodes will have relationships going in both directions. (Also, if you re-ran that query, it would create yet another set of relationships.) Do you have a use case that really requires those relationships?

Comment: What exactly is the 'problem' you are facing? Is it showing an error message, or is the output not what you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given Apache AGE PostgreSQL query, the error is in the line AND id(a) != id(b). The use of the != it is supposed to be <>

Setup:
Insert multiple vertices with different **vid** and make some of their title not set to 'backend' to check whether it gets connected or not

Data setup (3 vertices with title backend and 3 with another titles)

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('my_graph', $$
    CREATE (a:Person {title: 'backend', vid: 1})
    RETURN a                                                            
$$) as (a agtype);
```

Query

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('devbook', $$
    MATCH (a: Person), (b: Person)
    WHERE a.title = 'backend' AND b.title = 'backend' AND id(a) <> id(b)
    CREATE (a)-[e:STACK_MATCH { title: 'backend' }]->(b) RETURN e
$$) as (relationship agtype);
```

Output

```
                                                                    relationship                                                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 1125899906842625, "label": "STACK_MATCH", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"title": "backend"}}::edge
 {"id": 1125899906842626, "label": "STACK_MATCH", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"title": "backend"}}::edge
 {"id": 1125899906842627, "label": "STACK_MATCH", "end_id": 844424930131969, "start_id": 844424930131970, "properties": {"title": "backend"}}::edge
 {"id": 1125899906842628, "label": "STACK_MATCH", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131970, "properties": {"title": "backend"}}::edge
 {"id": 1125899906842629, "label": "STACK_MATCH", "end_id": 844424930131969, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"title": "backend"}}::edge
 {"id": 1125899906842630, "label": "STACK_MATCH", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"title": "backend"}}::edge
(6 rows)
```

Result is only connection between backend nodes

(Demo through AGE-viewer)

[image: Demo through AGE-viewer]

Nodes output

```
FROM cypher('my_graph', $$
    MATCH (n) RETURN n                             
$$) as (a agtype);                                                      
                                                  a                                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Person", "properties": {"vid": 3, "title": "backend"}}::vertex
 {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Person", "properties": {"vid": 2, "title": "backend"}}::vertex
 {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Person", "properties": {"vid": 1, "title": "backend"}}::vertex
 {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Person", "properties": {"vid": 4, "title": "notbackend"}}::vertex
 {"id": 844424930131973, "label": "Person", "properties": {"vid": 5, "title": "notbackend"}}::vertex
 {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Person", "properties": {"vid": 6, "title": "notbackend"}}::vertex
(6 rows)
```

Note that != is replaced with <> you can find that on the documentation of AGE.
And **vid** is vertex id would be a user identified property

References:

- https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/comparability.html